# Validate that response JSON is Map and not Array of Maps

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

While writing contract-tests for our simple REST API, I noticed that I could not express the difference between a resource returning a list/array of my entity and one, returning only one instance of the entity.

```
response { // (6)
    [..]
    body([[
                  id               : $(regex('.*')),
                  title            : $('Title1'),
          ], [
                  id               : $(regex('.*')),
                  title            : $('Title2'),
          ]
    ])
    headers {// (9)
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
```

Where I test the resource, returning a single entry with:

```
response { // (6)
    [..]
    body([
            id: $(regex('.*')),
            title: $(producer(regex('.*')), consumer('Der Titel1'))
    ]
    )
    headers {// (9)
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the lower spec also perfectly validates against the actual resource returning a list of my entities..

How could I express the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the `testMatchers` section to either provide an explicit JSON Path that will validate your case in the way you wish or provide the `byType` chcek that way it will check whether you have a List or a Map (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.4.RELEASE/#_dynamic_properties_in_matchers_sections).